# How do I tell the difference between a storm trooper and a clone trooper by looking?

Tags: star-wars

There must be a way, and I’ve heard it’s the about the helmet but not what the differences are. In the movies, the characters have no trouble telling the difference, so logically there should be a way, but anything I find only confuses me more.

Comment: The clone troopers can actually hit their target!!

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of differences but since you only asked about the look

Stormtrooper uniforms are what most people recognize as classic Star Wars minion gear. They’re all white, have “ski visor” styled glasses, and helmets that are similar in style to Darth Vader’s black helmet. Stormtroopers are very uniform in appearance throughout the franchise.

Clone troopers, on the other hand, have a different array of uniforms depending on what point in the Star Wars franchise they’re in. For the most part, their helmets have narrower vision windows, have less bulky helmet designs, and also tend to have some color markings on their uniform.

For the most part, all clone troopers will look nearly identical to Jango Fett. However, there were aberrations that popped up during the making of clone batches. These aberrations occasionally would give clone troopers some of the following traits:

- Different Eye Color. This was the most common aberration seen among clone troopers, by a long shot.
- Differing Facial Feature. Some clones had higher cheekbones, others had larger eyes, while even more had different jawlines than Jango Fett. Most of these facial feature differences weren’t very noticeable.

Further, Clone Troopers adopted many different colour codes into their armour, while Stormtroopers maintained an all white attire

Apart from the expert ARC trooper and the standard pilot, medic and commando variants, clones had a little diversity. Flame Trooper, Riot Control Trooper, Bomb-Squad Trooper, Scuba Trooper and Assault trooper were the different kind of clones. Apart from these, Stormtroopers had further diversified with Sniper Troopers, Sand Troopers and Snow Troopers. There were also Shadow Troopers with cloaking technology. Magma Troopers could endure adverse temperatures. And a few more varieties existed too, such as the Heavy Trooper.

[image]

[image]

You can see the difference in their helmets specifically their eyes.

[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxwJuRzaL5AhWUR2wGHeX0DGMQFnoECAoQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstarships.com%2Fstormtrooper-vs-clone-trooper%2F&usg=AOvVaw2HAol5b67Toa5R-ZXiC5mn)

[Source](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjxwJuRzaL5AhWUR2wGHeX0DGMQFnoECFcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.quora.com%2FWhat-is-the-difference-between-a-Stormtrooper-and-a-Clone-Trooper-What-are-the-similarities&usg=AOvVaw0F9GIb8WSOU4RQK_G9u8vv)